# What is cryptic line of code for this statement?

Tags: c, pointers, member-access

For example:

- `temp->next = NULL` is same as `(*temp).next = NULL`
- `list->next->next = temp` is same as ??

Comment: Side note: something line `list->next->next` is always wrong if we're talking linked lists. If `list->next` is NULL, `list->next->next` will trigger undefined behaviour (most likely some crash).

Comment: @Jabberwocky: "always" ? No. If you know that `list->next` points to a valid item, there is no problem. This construct can be met when you want to delete an element from a list.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I should have written "_is **almost** always wrong_". I've seen this often if buggy code that tries to delete a noide from a linked list, and it fails if the last node is to be deleted.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: what about "is dangerous" ? (Note that `list->next` can be dangerous as well.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust last comment edited. Yes of course `list->next` can be dangerous, but if `list` is invalid, there are serious other ponblems in the code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: er, in most linked list traversals, the running pointer ends-up being null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
list->next->next = temp;
```

can be rewritten in several ways. For example

```
( *list ).next->next = temp;
```

or

```
( *( *list ).next ).next = temp;
```

or

```
( *list ->next ).next = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as `(*(*list).next).next = temp`

Answer (score 0):

```
temp->next = NULL;
(*temp).next = NULL;
```

Both lines are equivilent (assigning `NULL` to the value of `next`).  The difference is that in the second, the pointer is dereferenced (`(*temp)`), which means we access the property with `.` instead of `->`.

The operator `->` is 'dereference'.  It's specifically there to save you from the verbosity of dereferencing through `*`, especially when you often need the parentheses to make it work as intended.  So do it like that.

```
list->next->next = temp;
```

This assigns the value of `temp` to the `next` property of the `next` list item.  This might fail if `list` or `list->next` isn't a pointer to a valid memory location (such as `NULL`).

And when I say 'fail', I mean the behaviour is undocumented, because you will just be writing over something (some runtimes will catch assignment to NULL) that will likely cause hard to predict behaviour.  It might appear to work now, and come and bite you later.  They can be tricky to find, so pay attention ;-)

Generally, when assigning to a pointer, especially when chained in this way, make sure you have an appropriate guard condition/context to know that you can trust its doing the right thing.

```
if (list && list->next) {
  list->next->next = temp;
} else {
  // eek!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as

```
list[0].next[0].next= temp;
```